# Early Klein Mountain Bike - need suggested component rebuild ideas

Tags: product-rec

This classic ride, (a hand-me-down, no less,) has served me well for more than a few years. The componentry is showing its age and the drivetrain really needs to be replaced, but I can find no specs on the BB threading or the rear fork width (if that's the term) so I can get the right upgrades. I'm planning to use this stunning contraption to commute to work, which combines mostly suburban-urban streets with a little dirt thrown in.

Can anyone help me find specs on this wonderful ride so I can hit the road when the warm weather kicks in? Much appreciated.

[image: Klein Mountain Bike]

Comment: www.sheldonbrown.com

Comment: Do you have a local bike shop that could take a look at it?  It is impossible to assess a bike for repair without actually seeing the bike.  I recommend that you bring it in and have them take a look at it.  Most good bike shops will at least put it in the stand and assess it for free.

Comment: I'm completely capable of upgrading the bike myself. I just need some specs on the frame & whatnot. Thanks.

Comment: That looks like a Klein Rascal: http://www.oldklein.com/vanha/Rascal.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have to pore over photos and Klein fan-sites like [oldklein.com](http://www.oldklein.com/) to find the specs, answering one question at a time.

In terms of the BB, I believe they were press-fit bearings, in press-fit cups (like an old BMX), so you might have to remove them, measure them, and then approach an engineering supplies shop for replacements. Bearings are surprisingly universal so don't be put-off too easily by people saying "ah they are proprietary Klein bearings, forged by Klein faeries from Klein precious metals".. they are probably available!

The rear hub width can be measured easily by you, it's probably 135mm but that's a guess. Things like cranks will be square taper LX types, maybe something oddly 90's like bio-pace oval rings :)

I can't guess the model, but I don't remember the Pulse or Attitude havign internal top cable routing like that, so is it an Adroit? If so, I'm pretty sure they aren't the original forks.

Let us know how you get on! Lovely bike, I lusted after Kleins when I was 15!

Answer (score 1):

You can find replacement parts on Ebay...mostly (some ridiculous prices for items).  The bottom bracket is the easiest to fix by buying a Phil Wood outboard press fit bottom bracket
http://philwood.com/store/page40.html . 
It is part BBCGN.

Tires and wheels are easy since you can still get 26 inch rims and tires.  Tires have greatly improved over the years.

You can update the steering column using and adapter (lots of options) that will allow you to use a modern stem and handlebar.

You can still buy cantilever brakes by Avid.

Good luck.